# how to animate navbar on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like to ask if there is a way to use jQuery animate() method to animate horizontal navbar's top property on window scroll.

Here is code I use:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
if (window.scrollY > 200) {
    $('#navbar').css({top:"100px"});
}
else {
    $('#navbar').css({top:"0px"});
}
},false);
```

CSS:

```
#navbar{
top:0;
position:fixed;
transition: top 0.5s;
}
```

When you scroll down 200px the navbar changes its top position from 0 to 100px;
This works fine, but if I change methods and put .animate instead of .css,

```
$('#navbar').animate({top:"100px"});
```

it stops working. Any ideas why?

Comment: This can be achieved by using CSS3 transitions. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185001/transitioning-affixed-navigation-bar-css

Comment: Please see the updated my second link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with css `transition` and how you can achieve this is with jQuery `addClass` instead of `css()`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jv0qvvp2/1)

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
        if (!$('.navbar').hasClass('expand')) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('expand');
        }
    } else {
        if ($('.navbar').hasClass('expand')) {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('expand');
        }
    }
});


.navbar {
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    transition: top 0.5s;
}

.navbar.expand {
    top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scroll event listener execute every time when you scroll page on every pixel, and animate starts from begin. This gives unexpected results.

http://jsfiddle.net/29tkxawy/

You should be leave as is (with `.css()`).

Or like this without css transition:

http://jsfiddle.net/29tkxawy/10/