# Bootstrap navigation affix bug - menu becomes jittery, jumpy on long pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, affix

I'm building a website using bootstrap affix to manage the main menu. It seems to work perfectly on fairly short pages but I find that as page length increases the menu starts to get jumpy, jittery, as you scroll so I created 3 sample pages to illustrate the problem. Other than some extra content to promote additional scrolling the implementation of affix is identical.

Typically when I scroll I use the navigator scrollbar - the behavior appears more pronounced using the scrollbar vs keyboard up/down arrows and perhaps more so on Linux Firefox vs Chrome.

The affix CSS settings:

```
.affix {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}

.affix + .affix-content-container
{
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I use the class, affix-content-container, on the div to contain all the body content following the bootstrap nav.  Here are the links to the 3 varying length demo pages:

[affix short page](http://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/affix/affix-short.php)

[affix medium page](http://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/affix/affix-medium.php)

[affix long page](http://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/affix/affix-long.php)

I've looked at some other websites which use something like affix, much longer pages, and they seem to behave more smoothly. Any suggestion how to smooth this out?

Here is a link to a video from Firefox. With each page I first use the mouse and scrollbar, then just the arrow keys. The green horizontal line is there for perspective, helps illustrate the problem.

[Affix Video Demo](http://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/affix/affix-video.php)

---

Workaround Solution Update: 2018-01-23

I added CSS transitions to .affix, in-out, etc, but they have no effect. It is still jumpy.  So I thought back to the goal which is a navbar that scrolls to the top and smoothly fixes to the top of the page. I'm not much good with javascript, but I found some code and modified it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 120) {
      $('nav').addClass('fix-navbar-position');
    } else {
     $('nav').removeClass('fix-navbar-position');
    }
  });
</script>
```

I set the height of the header to 120, the scroll then fix height:

```
header { height: 120px; }
```

I found that if I set it up as:  that I was seeing some odd margins or extra vertical padding, so I separated it so that nav would be an outer container only - and this worked:

```
<nav>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse">
```

The problem seemed to have something to do with the .navbar styling. To see the workaround solution visit: [javascript-scroll-fix](http://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/affix/javascript-scroll+fix.php)

Comment: I cannot discern any meaningful difference in the scrolling mechanics between macOS Safari, Firefox, and Chrome.  This includes scrolling using a mouse wheel, manually dragging the scroll bar, or using the up/down arrows on my keyboard.

Comment: With the long page in particular it is significant enough to feel unprofessional. I'll look into creating a screencast. It is ugliest when dragging the scrollbar in Firefox 57.0.1 although I can't imagine the version being relevant.

Comment: Now with regard to your examples I would note that jQuery is NOT loading for me.  That is probably preventing Affix from operating properly. To clarify, there is a 404 for an include for http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: There was another obscure jquery file there working but yes I had the wrong link to the library. I fixed that, also to make it more liveish adjusted the amount of dummy content in the medium to roughly equal that of the home page of devel and adjusted long to parallel the sitemap. The problem remains. I plan to do a short video later today.

Comment: Added the video link at the bottom of the original post

Comment: Is it possible there is a misunderstanding here of what Affix does or how it works?  Because your video just shows the Affix element (your nav) toggling on and off as needed based on your scrolling.

Comment: My understanding is that you attach affix to an item, in this case, the nav and set the height properties of the elements above that item. Once you scroll, as you scroll that much in pixels, the item that is set to affix, will stick to the top of the page like a true fixed (at top) navbar. I'm not sure what you mean by toggling (on/off?); it should scroll up then smoothly become fixed at the top. I see jumping.

Comment: Your understanding is correct; with the exception that the Bootstrap Affix component does not, on its own, provide any smooth transitioning.  That is typically achieved through CSS transitions or JavaScript that is attached to the event - often in scenarios where the affixed navigation appears only when the scroll event is triggered.

Comment: CSS transitions are commonly used for creating time-based changes like hovering over a button and make the color change gradually or creating a linear swipe, perhaps adding effects to images - not fixing problems like this. Can you recommend how to fix this?

Comment: I thought... I had? Everything you've posted as the problem is just how Affix works 'out of the box'.  If you want a smoother transition you need to apply those transitions, either via CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: Strange out of the box behavior but okay. Can you point me to how to apply a transition to smooth out the behavior? I'd imagine this would help out thousands more who have encountered the same problem.

Comment: For options on that I would recommend searching Stack Overflow as that's been answered numerous times; here is one answer from back when Bootstrap v2.x was a thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185001/transitioning-affixed-navigation-bar-css

Comment: I tried applying CSS transitions to .affix and other elements to no avail. So I stepped back and set up a workaround using javascript, no more affix. I added this to the original post. I looked through the other affix posts - none seemed to be relevant to this problem.